# C# remote PowerShell calculated property returns null

Tags: c#, powershell, properties, null

I'm working on a C# web application which handles our Exchange 2016 mailboxes.
It's a requirement that the web application and our Exchange 2016 installation are kept separate, so I'm using remote PowerShell to access our Exchange 2016.
I have already tried the "New-PSSession, Import-PSSession, etc." approach, but find it to be very slow, so I would prefer not to use that approach.

If I execute the following code snippet, the calculated property "TotalItemSize" contains valid data.

```
var script = "Get-Mailbox -Identity XYZ | Select-Object -Property Name, Database, " +
               "@{ n = \"TotalItemSize\"; e = { (Get-MailboxStatistics -Identity XYZ).TotalItemSize }}";
pipeline.Commands = new PS.PSCommand().AddScript(script);
var result = pipeline.Invoke();

/* here result.Properties["TotalItemSize"].Value contains data */
```

If I execute the following code snippet, the calculated property "TotalItemSize" contains null.

```
pipeline.Commands = new PSCommand().AddCommand("Get-Mailbox").AddParameter("Identity", "XYZ")
                    .AddCommand("Select-Object").AddParameter("Property",
                      new List<object>{
                        "Name",
                        "Database",
                        new Hashtable {
                          {"Name", "TotalItemSize"}, {"Expression", ScriptBlock.Create("(Get-MailboxStatistics -Identity XYZ).TotalItemSize")}
                        }
                      });
var result = pipeline.Invoke();

/* here result.Properties["TotalItemSize"].Value is null */
```

Can anyone tell me what is wrong with the last code snippet, since the calculated property "TotalItemSize" is null?